# In Swagger 2.0, what should "default" within an array parameter actually mean?

Tags: json, schema, swagger

In the well-known petstore swagger, the findByStatus endpoint takes a status:

```
"parameters": [
    {
        "name": "status",
        "in": "query",
        "description": "Status values that need to be considered for filter",
        "required": true,
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
                "available",
                "pending",
                "sold"
            ],
            "default": "available"
        },
        "collectionFormat": "multi"
    }
]
```

While the default value could be implied from this, from a programmatic perspective what should be expected as the value for "status" (and for other parameters in a similar case)?

- The value is type array, it doesn't have a default
- Each item is a string, one of available, pending or sold, and the default if not supplied is "available"

How would you use "default" for an array of arbritrary length? The default supplied is for the string, not the array so:

- Does this imply that the array has  no default value?
- Does it imply that the array has a default value of an array with one item that is the default value for the array items?
- Does it imply an array of arbritrary length where all the values are the default value for the array items?